# Geometric Interpretation of Liouville's Theorem?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> The only bounded entire functions in $\mathbb{C}$ are constants.

Could someone please give me a geometric interpretation of the theorem above? I don't intuitively understand why it's true.

Also, aren't periodic functions counterexamples? i.e. $\sin(z)$?

Comment: A slightly different way of phrasing it: let $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$. $\mathrm{im} f$ is either a point or dense.

Comment: $\sin(z)$ is periodic in the real direction, not in the imaginary

Comment: $Sin(z)$ isn't bounded!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interpretation based on [a proof by Edward Nelson](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1961-012-06/S0002-9939-1961-0259149-4/S0002-9939-1961-0259149-4.pdf).

If $f : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is entire (*), then it verifies the [Mean value property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#The_mean_value_property): its value at the center of a disk equals to the average of its values on that same disk.

Consider two points $a, b \in \mathbb{C}, a \neq b$, a radius $R > 0$ and the two disks $D_1, D_2$ of radius $R$ centered respectively at $a$ and $b$.

We have (*Mean value property*):
$f(a) = \frac{1}{\pi R^2} \iint_{D_1}{f}{dS} = \frac{1}{\pi R^2}( \iint_{D_1 \cap D_2}{f}{dS} + \iint_{D_1 \setminus D_2}{f}{dS})$

Doing the same for $b$ and $D_2$ we find:

$f(a) - f(b) = \frac{1}{\pi R^2} (\iint_{D_1 \setminus D_2}{f}{dS} - \iint_{D_2 \setminus D_1}{f}{dS})$

If $f$ is bounded, those two integrals converge to zero when $R \rightarrow \infty$, because the area on which we integrate becomes negligible compared to the whole area of the disks (see picture below) and we find that $f(a) = f(b)$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$: $f$ is constant.

[image: Disks intersecting]

(*) same proof still holds for harmonic functions, since we only use the mean value property

Answer (score 0):

The geometric interpretation is the following : any holomorphic function of the Riemann Sphere/complex projective line is constant.

Edit : I put the proof of the previous fact in the general case of a compact Riemann surface in comments below.

Comment: Why does holomorphism imply constantness though?

Comment: The Maximum Modulus Principle is the key !

Comment: Of course, the compacity of the complex projective line is crucial.

Comment: There's something a bit off here. Rational functions are holomorphic on the Sphere. Maybe you mean functions from the Sphere to the Plane are constant.

Comment: @JoeManlove : There's nothing off here, except your comment. By holomorphic I mean, as everyone on earth, holomorphic with values in $\mathbf{C}$. Now, let $X$ be a **compact** Riemann surface, and $f$ an holomorphic function. $X$ being compact, the real continuous function $|f|$ reaches its maximum at some $x\in X$. Let $\varphi : U \rightarrow V$ be a chart around $x$ (that is $x\in U$) with $U$ connected, and $V$ an open neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbf{C}$, and $\varphi(x)=0$.

Comment: @JoeManlove : Then $f \circ {\varphi}^{-1}$ is an holomorphic function defined on an open subset of $\mathbf{C}$ such that $|f \circ {\varphi}^{-1}|$ reaches its maximum at $0$. By the maximum modulus principle, $|f \circ {\varphi}^{-1}|$ is constant on $V$, that is, $\varphi$ is constant (equal to some $z_0\in\mathbf{C}$ on $U$. Now, if $f$ is equal to $z_0$ on whole $X$, the set $f^{-1}(\{z_0\})$ has no limit point, which contradicts the fact that it contains whole $U$. Therefore $f$ is constant (equal to this $z_0$) on $X$.

Comment: @JoeManlove : Application : OP's question. Take $X$ equal to the projective line (or Riemann sphere or whatever you call it) $ \mathbf{P}^{1,\textrm{an.}}\left(\mathbf{C}\right)$.

Comment: @JoeManlove : A rational function on the Riemann sphere is an holomorphic function from $ \mathbf{P}^{1,\textrm{an.}}\left(\mathbf{C}\right)$ into $ \mathbf{P}^{1,\textrm{an.}}\left(\mathbf{C}\right)$ (not into $\mathbf{C}$) of a certain type : it is rational in an affine chart. Be an least polite and un-downvote my answer, now that you understand it. :-)

Comment: @dfg : If you're happy with my answer, upvote ! :-)

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. In addition, I think people who work in complex dynamics on the Sphere would disagree with your definition of holomorphic.

Comment: @JoeManlove : Sorry, thought it was you. My bad. To finish on the definition point : there are also people who call a glass a table. It is of course totally legit, but they will have issues when communicating with people who call a table a table.

Comment: The questions asks for holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$, not on the Riemann sphere. You have to at least invoke Riemann's removability theorem or something to extend your function to the sphere.